# Why use codes for login names

Tags: security

I consult to many companies and I notice that some of them use codes rather than some variant of the user's name for their Windows login ID, e.g. u54aju or k56743...

What is the reasoning here?  What's wrong with first.last or similar?  The users don't seem to know.

Comment: Security? It mean hackers can't guess user names if they have already got email addresses for example (company emails are quite often firstname.lastname@ or initial.lastname@ or similar and the email naming scheme is often easy to find from a company website) ...

Comment: Your email address is probably chris.paterson@example.com ;)

Comment: Because they are idiots.  We came up with a very simple and effective way to stop guessing passwords in the 1960's: after you try and fail a few times, you don't get to try any more.  See also: https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 1):

From an IT perspective, large organisations like to have standard behaviours.  If you use a username based on a person's real life name then you end up with the definite possibility of collisions (e.g. John Smith - depending on your country of origin).  So for the sake of consistency they would use some unique identifier that is probably related to employee number or similar.  This sort of practice would then trickle down into the rest of the industry even for significantly smaller organisations.

Answer (score 0):

Login information comes in two parts - the username and the password.  If the username uses the user's name and a standard scheme, half of all the login information can be guessed accurately.

For instance, Sam Swift has a login of `sswift` and Derek Diggle is `ddiggle`, then its safe to assume all users follow that scheme.  While it is more convenient, it does lower overall security.

Some organizations want that extra security at the cost of convenience.

Answer (score 0):

In my first fulltime job, the first widespread system (nearly) everyone logged into was the mainframe. Mainframe OSs of decades ago had a limited username space - such as 8 characters. Using an employee number fit nicely in that space without having to sort out collisions with using name abbreviations.

Given the status of "the mainframe" in many older organisations, whatever standard was chosen for them often trickled down to other systems, such as LANs.